# Error while compiling C# winForms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to build my first Winforms using C# in Visual Studio 2010. It's just a simple form with a button click event that closes the form. 
Here's the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnEnglish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = " Do you speak English? ";

        }

        private void btnSpanish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = " Do you speak Spanish? ";
        }

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

This seems as if some configuration properties or something like that is missing in my project by I am unable to find out what exactly?

Some search led me to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa13yay7.aspx but I am not sure how to apply this in my code or project properties or if there is some other issue?

Comment: is your source checked in to source control?

Comment: Can't figure out much , try rebuilding or closing VS n reopening VS n check?

Comment: how much simple is your code? can you delete it and rewrite it? or maybe just close the VS, reopen, recreate the project and add the form? can you do that?

Comment: @LiranElisha i already did it...let me edit the question and post the code as well

Comment: @AlvinWong have updated the question...hope it makes sense now

Comment: have update the question

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5c3ehka(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: dear @kewal i'm sorry but i think you'll have to reinstall VS..

Comment: @LiranElisha it seems so :(... have tried every other alternative i could think of

Comment: i know how it fells @kewal, but the only thing i can suggest before deleting is maybe get a good working version of mscorlib to check if maybe that's the corrupted file

Comment: yeah...thats a valid suggestion...thanks...will do it

Comment: Try to set target framework

Comment: @NakulChaudhary... have done that...no effect....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this answer on [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/519214/silverlight-4-application-project-remove-reference-to-mscorlib-or-system-core-and-they-cant-be-readded#details) has somethig to do with your issue. The MS team comment:

> This is a known issue that we will not be able to fix for VS2010. The
>   workaround, once in this situation, is to edit the project file and
>   manually re-add the reference

So, in your *.csproj* file, add the missing reference:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
```

Comment: Ive ran in to this problem my self, the only way to fix it was doing this solution.

Comment: This workaround only works when `<NoStdLib>True</NoStdLib>` present in the project file.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to pay attention to,

1. In your question, please provide enough details. You don't even paste the error message, which makes it hard to join the discussion.
2. Learn how MSBuild translates a project to C# command line.

That latter is difficult to achieve, but if you enable verbose logging of MSBuild, you will see tons on log entries that show you what is under the hood.

About the reference to `mscorlib`, in most cases it is implicit. There is no `<Reference Include="mscorlib">` normally, and no `<NoStdLib>True</NoStdLib>`. In this way, MSBuild will call C# compiler with /nostdlib-.

For certain project types (.NET CF projects typically), VS adds `<NoStdLib>True</NoStdLib>` to project file, and also `<Reference Include="mscorlib">` to the corresponding platform's `mscorlib.dll`. A sample file can be found [here](https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/SharpSnmpLib/sharpsnmplib.cf35.csproj). In this way, MSBuild calls C# compiler with /nostdlib+.

Thus, if you experience any compilation issue related to mscorlib, please check your project file, as well as MSBuild verbose logging. That should let you easily know what is wrong.

Updated:
http://www.lextm.com/2013/08/how-to-resolve-mscorlib-related-issues-in-visual-studiomsbuild/

Answer (score 1):

A search for "Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported" shows that the reason is that "mscorlib" isn't referenced. So add that reference. There is also the suggestion that you need to create a new solution (which should contain that reference). You can copy your code to that new solution.

Also, you found the "/nostdlib" compiler option. You do *not* want to use that, because you *need* that dll. [That page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa13yay7.aspx) mentions a "Do not reference mscorlib.dll property" (which I don't see in VS2012). You *do* want to reference mscorlib, so don't change it from the default.

Comment: but he said he recreated the project...

Comment: yes i did recreate the project

Comment: And if i try to add it it says: "A reference to 'mscorlib' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system."